# Checking if Element is Present in an Array in Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm encountering an issue while trying to check if a string is present in an array within my Rails application. The include? method seems to be giving unexpected results.

I have an array named @categories which holds a list of strings like ["poverty", "hunger"]. I'm trying to use this array to pre-select checkboxes in a form based on whether the values where selected last time.

In this code, I print the values @categories, @categories&.include?(un_kind[1]), and un_kind[1], which give me the following respective values:["poverty", "hunger"] false poverty

```
<%= @categories %>
<% Array(t("#{cat_l}.enums.un_kind").invert).each do |un_kind| %>
  <%= @categories&.include?(un_kind[1]) %>
  <%= un_kind[1] %>
  <div class="form-check">
    <%= check_box_tag "un_kind[]", un_kind[1], @categories&.include?(un_kind[1]), class: 'form-check-input' %>
    <%= label_tag "un_kind_#{un_kind[1]}", un_kind[0], class: 'form-check-label' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is a string vs symbol issue. You're getting your `un_kind[1]` from your i18n locale lookup, which means it will be `:poverty` NOT `"poverty"`. Therefore:

```rb
> ["poverty", "hunger"].include? :poverty
false
```

...as opposed to:

```rb
> ["poverty", "hunger"].include? "poverty"
true
```

The confusing part here is that when you print a symbol it's automatically converted to its string form. This is why generally for debugging it's better to use `inspect` on the objects that you're printing, that will usually give you better visibility as to what's going on.

I'm sure you're way ahead of me, the simple fix is to `.to_s` your `un_kind[1]` object: `@categories&.include?(un_kind[1].to_s)`